# Dynamic serialization using Jackson - removing fields with specific annotations

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, annotations

Went down a path of creating an annotation that would dynamic determine whether a field should be serialized or not.

The annotation's implementation is as follows:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = HiddenFieldSerializer.class)
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Hidden {
}
```

Now the code for the Serializer:

```java
public class HiddenFieldSerializer
        extends StdSerializer<String>
        implements ContextualSerializer {

    public HiddenFieldSerializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value,
                          JsonGenerator jgen,
                          SerializerProvider provider) {
        try {
            provider.defaultSerializeNull(jgen);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov,
                                              BeanProperty property) {
        return shouldHide() ?
                new HiddenFieldSerializer() : new StringSerializer();
    }

    public boolean shouldHide() {
        /* Simplifying this */
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

A little bit of code to show how it works:

```java
public class Test {
    static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);

    static class User {
        @JsonProperty
        String username;

        @Hidden
        @JsonProperty
        String pin;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws JsonProcessingException {

        final POC.User u = new POC.User();
        u.username = "harry_potter";
        u.pin = "1298";

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(u));
    }
}
```

And the output is as follows:

```
{"username":"harry_potter","pin":null}
```

How do I get the field pin to be removed from the serialization instead of it being null? Obviously setting the mapper's properties was of very little user in such a context. Any suggestions? Thoughts? Maybe the whole thing is a bad idea?

Ideally I should be able to see the following:

```
{"username":"harry_potter"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to ignore a given property *statically* or *dynamically*. Anyways, looks like you have over-engineered it.

First of all, I want to make sure that you came across [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) before. If it doesn't suit your needs, you could define your custom ignore annotation as following:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Hidden {

}
```

Then pick the approach that best suit your needs:

### Approach #1

Extend [`JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.html) and override the method that checks for the ignore marker:

```java
public class CustomAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        return super.hasIgnoreMarker(m) || m.hasAnnotation(Hidden.class);
    }
}
```

Configure [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to use your annotation introspector:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomAnnotationIntrospector());
```

The annotation introspection *occurs only once per class* so you can not dynamically change the criteria you use (if any). A similar example can be seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021013/1426227).

### Approach #2

Extend [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) to modify the properties that will be serialized:

```java
public class CustomBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, 
            BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        return beanProperties.stream()
                .filter(property -> property.getAnnotation(Hidden.class) == null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Then add it to a [`Module`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.html) and register it to your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule() {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new CustomBeanSerializerModifier());
    }
});
```

This approach allows you to ignore properties dynamically.

Comment: I like the CustomSerializerModifier, not sure overriding the JacksonAnnotationInspector would help. Checking your solution now, thank you for the insight

Comment: CustomBeanSerializerModifier will also be called only once and subsequent calls on same object type will be cached. Is there a way we can call this modifier every time a object is serialized? My scenario is to check for certain permissions (which could change dynamically) during serialization.