# How to dynamically ignore a property on Jackson serialization

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have an entity with multiple `@ManyToOne` associations. I am using spring-boot to expose a REST API. Currently, I have multiple REST API's which return a JSON response of the whole entity, including associations.

But I don't want to serialize all associated objects in all REST APIs.

For example

- API-1 should return parent + associationA object
- API-2 should return parent + associationA + associationB object
- API-3 should return parent + associationB + associationC + associationD

So, in my serialization process, I want to ignore all association except associationA for API-1.

For API-2 I want to ignore other associations except A and B

---

How do I dynamically ignore these properties during Jackson serialization?

Notes:
I'm using the same class for each; I am not interested in creating a DTO for each API.

Any suggestions are kingly appreciated.

Comment: I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically/68837998#68837998

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've put together three approaches for performing dynamic filtering in Jackson. One of them must suit your needs.

### Using `@JsonView`

You could use [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html):

```java
public class Views {         
    interface Simple { }  
    interface Detailed extends Simple { }   
}
```

```java
public class Foo {

    @JsonView(Views.Simple.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Detailed.class)
    private String details;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@JsonView(Views.Detailed.class)
public Foo getFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    return foo;
}
```

Alternatively you can set the view dynamically with [`MappingJacksonValue`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonValue.html).

```java
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public MappingJacksonValue getFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    MappingJacksonValue result = new MappingJacksonValue(foo);
    result.setSerializationView(Views.Detailed.class);
    return result;
}
```

### Using a `BeanSerializerModifier`

You could extend [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) and then override the [`changeProperties()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html#changeProperties-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription-java.util.List-) method. It allows you to add, remove or replace any of properties for serialization, according to your needs:

```java
public class CustomSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
        BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        // In this method you can add, remove or replace any of passed properties

        return beanProperties;
    }
}
```

Then register the serializer as a module in your [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule() {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new CustomSerializerModifier());
    }
});
```

Check examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937136/1426227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796701/1426227).

### Using `@JsonFilter` with a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`

Another approach involves [`@JsonFilter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFilter.html):

```java
@JsonFilter("customPropertyFilter")
public class Foo {

    private String name;
    private String details;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Extend [`SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) and override the [`serializeAsField()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html#serializeAsField-java.lang.Object-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyWriter-) method according to your needs:

```java
public class CustomPropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen,
                                 SerializerProvider provider, 
                                 PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

        // Serialize a field
        // writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider, writer);

        // Omit a field from serialization
        // writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
    }
}
```

Then register the filter in your [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
        .addFilter("customPropertyFilter", new CustomPropertyFilter());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);
```

If you want to make your filter *"global"*, that is, to be applied to all beans, you can create a mix-in class and annotate it with `@JsonFilter("customPropertyFilter")`:

```java
@JsonFilter("customPropertyFilter")
public class CustomPropertyFilterMixIn {

}
```

Then bind the mix-in class to `Object`:

```java
mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, CustomPropertyFilterMixIn.class);
```

Comment: View is also similar to dto right? I have to create multiple view class with combination of associations.

Comment: @Achaius You could define two views: one view for one API and another view for the other API. Then reuse them in all model classes returned in your application.

Comment: Nope. The above API are the sample I have given. Actually I have 11 API with all combination of associations. So creating 2 views is not enouth. Any other possible suggestion?

Comment: Ok. will check this and let you know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static <T> String getNonNullFieldsSerialized(T object, ObjectMapper objectMapper)throws JsonProcessingException {

    Map<String, Object> objectMap = objectMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

    Map<String, Object> objectMapNonNullValues = objectMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(stringObjectEntry -> Objects.nonNull(stringObjectEntry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapNonNullValues);
  }
```

This will basically ignore all the fields that are non-null. Similarly you can ignore other fields by changing the map filter condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented dynamic filter on data getting from db and returning it using rest api.I have avoided using MappingJacksonValue.As it was getting issue while object chaining

```
@GetMapping("/courses")
    public ResponseEntity<JpaResponse> allCourse() throws Exception {
        JpaResponse response = null;
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
         mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        List<Course> course = service.findAllCourse();
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("name","reviews");
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("jpafilter", filter).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
                ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filterProvider);
        String writeValueAsString = writer.writeValueAsString(course);
        List<Course> resultcourse = mapper.readValue(writeValueAsString,List.class);
            response = new JpaResponse(HttpStatus.OK.name(),resultcourse);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

}

public class JpaResponse {
        private String status;
        private Object data;
        public JpaResponse() {
            super();
        }
        public JpaResponse(String status, Object data) {
            super();
            this.status = status;
            this.data = data;
        }
}
```