# How to ignore property in one Entity and not to ignore in another - JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have got 2 classes - 2 entities - Book and BookRentals. BookRentals takes Book object inside.

I want to ignore one of attribute from Book inside BookRentals. This is `available` attribute. 
I've got method that is rensponsible for finding all rentals. Output in JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "book": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Krzyżacy",
            "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
            "category": "powieść historyczna",
            "available": false
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "piotri",
            "password": "123"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, available is not necesessary here, but I cant make `@JsonIgnore` in Book class, because this variable is needed in finding all books:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Krzyżacy",
        "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
        "category": "powieść historyczna",
        "available": false
    }
]
```

Book class:

```
package bookrental.model.book;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    private String author;
    @NotNull
    private String category;
    private boolean available;

    public Book(String title, String author, String category, boolean available) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.category = category;
        this.available = available;
    }
}
```

BookRentals class

```
package bookrental.model.book;

import bookrental.model.account.User;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class BookRentals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Book book;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    public BookRentals(Book book, User user) {
        this.book = book;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: Add this "@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)" and see

Comment: @venkat where should I add this? In book class?

Comment: @Alien Im working on two different enteties. Link does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172496/how-to-dynamically-ignore-a-property-on-jackson-serialization

Comment: Add it in top of book rental class

Comment: @venkat i dont know what what the purpose, but nah. It doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ResponseEntity and JsonSerializer (include and exclude) jackson to do the same.

```
return new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).include("field1").exclude("field2").serialize(pojoObject);
```

And then from the controller return response like below.

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).include("field1").exclude("field2").serialize(pojoObject), headers,HttpStatus.OK);
```

Your controller method will look something like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUser(@RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) String userId)
    {

        User user = userService.findByUserId(userId);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class).include("field1").exclude("field2").serialize(user), headers,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Why do I need date here? Im working with spring boot, so @ResponseBody, headers are not necessary too, I think. So my Service method should looks like this: https://pastebin.com/tPUQe4DT ? I cannot resolve symbol of JSONSerializer and DateTransfomer.

Comment: date transform is used to manipulate the date patterns..if you dont want to use can remove it. @ResponseBody needed if you are not using Restcontroller. and for JSONSerializer  you should import it from import flexjson.JSONSerializer; and ensure that you have <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
   <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency> in pom.xml

Comment: hey, everything works fine, but I cant get rid of class property from JSON. It looks this: https://pastebin.com/3xSBgmiw How am I supposed to exclude it? In pastebin I paste also method.

Comment: exclude ("*.class")

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Mixin** to change the serialization behaviour for a class.
In your case, create a mixin which ignores the 'available' property:

```
public interface RentalBookMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    boolean isAvailable();
}
```

Now you can enable the mixin on the ObjectMapper when you serialize BookRentals:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
 mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Book.class, RentalBookMixin.class);
```

When serializing single Books, omit this mixin so the 'available' property gets serialized again.

Comment: Well, I should create interface and which class implements it? This is the only method that interface should contain? Where should I add ObjectMapper, in which class?

Comment: The interface is not implemented by anyone - it just serves for Jackson as a primary source for the JSON property configuration, overriding those on your Book class. The ObjectMapper configuration depends on the framework you use (JEE, Spring, ...), usually a default ObjectMapper is supplied, which can be overridden.

Comment: For more details see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: unfortunately, cant make it :( I don't know where to what write.