# how to set member variable in return object of restful controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

A packing class for restful controller return ,has three member variable: code, msg, data.Statement class of data is Object.data may be any entity class.Some members of entity should not appear in the return Json.Is there some way to config ?

I had know @JsonView upon a interface and get method can control whether member appear.But it controll code, msg, data not the member in data.Controller method return Result class like this

```
public class Result{
  private String code;
  private String msg;
  private User user;
}


public class User {
 private String userName;
 private String password;
}
```

I expect the result Json without password like this

```
{
  "code":1,
  "msg":"",
  "data":{
    "userName":"Ted"
   }
}
```

not like

```
{
  "code":1,
  "msg":"",
  "data":{
    "userName":"Ted",
    "password":"Tedisbear"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jackson?

Comment: use `@JsonIgnore` on getter

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the `password` field

```
public class User {
    private String userName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
}
```

That way it will never be part of the response.

You could also annotate the `getPassword()` method and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

With the default serialization of Spring Boot (using Jackson), there are three ways of doing that:

### Using `@JsonIgnore`

You can try to add the `@JsonIgnore` only on your getter:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
```

Or:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
```

### Using `@JsonProperty` access

You can add `@JsonProperty` annotation on your field:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

> WRITE_ONLY
>   Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set) for deserialization, but will not be read (get) on serialization, that is, the value of the property **is not included in serialization**.

### Using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

Adding the properties you want to ignore on your class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password"})
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}
```

I usually go with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` when I want to extend some class and ignore some properties of the parent.

Comment: it seems can not use like @jsonview that i can set some config to fit different situation

Comment: Might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172496/how-to-dynamically-ignore-a-property-on-jackson-serialization) can help you then