# JsonIgnore except one endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-view

I am developing app using spring boot and I just want to ignore a field while returning to the client but except one endpoint.

```
public class MyJwt {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Lob
@JsonIgnore
private String jwt;
private String reminderKey;
private String userAccountId;
private String clientKey;
private Timestamp createdDate;
private Timestamp expirationDate;
private byte statusCode;
```

How can I expose jwt to the client only for one endpoint?
Thanks

Comment: Good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172496/how-to-dynamically-ignore-a-property-on-jackson-serialization

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). With it, you can tell which properties to include in each view.
You could have 2 views:

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Internal extends Public {
    }
}
```

Then your model should look like:

```java
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
public class MyJwt {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Lob
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  private String jwt;
  private String reminderKey;
  private String userAccountId;
  private String clientKey;
  private Timestamp createdDate;
  private Timestamp expirationDate;
  private byte statusCode;
}
```

Then in your endpoints, you would use `@JsonView(Views.Public.class)` with the exception of the one that should include `jwt`, on which you should use `@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)`.

Comment: Thank you @João Dias it helped a lot

Comment: @MesutCan, in that case, consider accepting the answer as correct so that others can benefit from it by easily finding a possible solution to similar topics and the question is "closed". Thanks!